# Flash player right click have no setting can click

Tags: html, flash

The situation like the picture:

[image]

and my html to load flash is:

```
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="150" height="150" id="Test">
            <param name="movie" value="Test.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <embed src="Test.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
                width="150" height="150" name="Test"
                quality="high" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="true" 
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" 
                FlashVars="test=123">
            </embed>
        </object>
```

I meet the problem first time, can anyone tell me what exactly cause it?

Is the code(such as in actionscript) side or the html tag missing?

My flash player is 11.0.0 above, and when I try other code( other project), it works fine and can right click with settings.

The project can works but I need to show the setting panel some circumstance.

Nether Crome or FireFox I run the flash cannot have the setting...

Thanks in advance.

I also look the article:[Can't Left Click i Flash Players Settings Panel](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/952971)

but I don't have Quick time setup in my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the key point of my html that cause the problem!

The html :

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="150" height="150" id="Test">
```

just need to change the width tag like to be:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="150" id="Test">
```

I have seen that the setting panel have some 'location' in the middle or what, so if I change the width 'too short', the setting panel cannot be click.

I still don't know the real reason, hope somebody face it can try it.

Comment: That is, the width shouldn't too small, or it will not have setting panel of the flash player.